# Django form is not saving when I have action = to desired url

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

If I use action="" in my django form, the form works properly but sends the user to the wrong page. I want the user to go back to the macro/ page upon form submission, but when I add that url to action (like action="{% url 'macro' %}", it goes to the page but the form doesn't save. Any suggestion on how to handle this? Code below:

**(Option 1)** macro_update.html -> the form here works properly, but takes the user to the wrong page

```
                <ul>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ macro_form.as_ul }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </ul>
```

**(Option 2)** macro_update.html -> the user is redirected to the right page upon submission, but the form data doesn't update/save

```
                <ul>
                    <form action="{% url 'macro' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ macro_form.as_ul }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </ul>
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def macroUpdate(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        macro_form = MacroForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if macro_form.is_valid():
            macro_form.save()
            messages.success(request,('Your macros were successfully updated!'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,('Unable to complete request'))
        return redirect("profile")

    macro_form = MacroForm(instance=request.user.profile)    
    context = {"user":request.user, "macro_form":macro_form } 
    return render(request, 'macro_update.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),
    path('profile/', views.profilePage, name='profile'),
    path('profile/update/', views.profileUpdate, name='profile-update'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout-user'),
    path('macro/', views.macroPage, name='macro'),
    path('macro/update/', views.macroUpdate, name='macro-update'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the user to go back to the macro/ page upon form submission, but when I add that url to action (like action="{% url 'macro' %}", it goes to the page but the form doesn't save.

It is because form data must go to `macroUpdate` view to save not `macroPage`, to redirect on macro page after form submission you can use `redirect("macro")` so:

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def macroUpdate(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        macro_form = MacroForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if macro_form.is_valid():
            macro_form.save()
            messages.success(request,('Your macros were successfully updated!'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,('Unable to complete request'))
        return redirect("macro")

    macro_form = MacroForm(instance=request.user.profile)    
    context = {"user":request.user, "macro_form":macro_form } 
    return render(request, 'macro_update.html', context)
```

Just remove the `action` attribute in from tag of `macro_update.html` since Django always takes current page route so:

```html
<ul>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ macro_form.as_ul }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</ul>
```